# Access the local Json file data after hosting to server using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Dont mark it duplicate as i did not found any solution for this.
If possible help me.

I have a file named `category.json` which i have placed near `index.html` file having following data in json file.

```
[{"name":"veg"},{"name","non-veg"}]
```

Now i have get that data using both  $resource and $http while working with the local system with no worries.

My query is, after hosting this into the server showing `file not found 404 error`.

Though we can do this by declaring it by directly with `var`, `$scope` but i need to do it with local json file only

Comment: Open the developer console and see the network tab. The call URL will be displayed. See if you have the JSON file in that location. 404 means not found. Nothing else

Comment: Yes, what u said is ok. already i checked it. its showing me 404 error

Comment: What is unclear about a 404 error? It means that URL does not point to the file. We can't tell why that is because we know nothing about your server.

Comment: check `developer tools` if you are accessing the correct url or not. May be you have hardcoded your local url in the get request.

Comment: did you tried giving that relative path ?

Comment: no need for the relative path as it with index file. I have placed that json file same place of index file

Answer (score 0):

When server give us 404 that means server unable to find your requested file or some reason file or its extension blocked for security reason.

Do these step to resolve your problem:

1. Check in developer console (Network tab), Is path is ok or there is some problem.
2. If path is ok then Open that path directly in browser
3. If browser still showing 404 then check server settings and allow **.json** extension. Map MIME of **.json** extension as `application/json`
4. If browser not showing 404 it just happening with your `index.html` file then please provide your code to understand that.

Answer (score -1):

First check the console, as this might be the path issue.

Try to give a correct path(may be you can try the path as **"./file_name.json"**)